# Poisson Distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The range of a random variable $X =\{1,2,3,4,\dots\}$ and the probabilities are given by $P(X=k) = \frac{3^{ck}}{k!}$ where $k \in \{1,2,3,4,\dots\}$ and $c$ is constant, then what is $c$?

i) $\frac{1}{2} \log(\log 2)$

ii) $\log_3(\log 2)$

iii) $\frac{\log_e (\log 2)}{\log_3 e}$

iv) $\log_2(\log 3)$

My approach: Comparing it with $\frac{\lambda^x}{e^\lambda x!}$ I got $\frac \lambda{e^\lambda} = 3^c$ which implies $\log_3\lambda - \lambda \log_3 e = c$. How do I  proceed to given options form? <s>This question is from Poisson distribution.</s>

Comment: I'm glad you fixed that. This was _not_ a Poisson distribution. For starters, the possible values excluded $0$, which _is_ a possible value for a Poisson random variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of your probabilities must be $1$:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X=k)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{3^{ck}}{k!}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}=e^{x}-1$$
With $x=3^c$. Thus
$$1=\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X=k)=e^{3^c}-1$$

Thus $3^c=\ln 2$, then $c\ln 3=\ln\ln 2$ and $c=\frac{\ln \ln 2}{\ln 3}=\log_3{\ln 2}$.

This also means $P(X=k)=\frac{(\ln 2)^k}{k!}$.

Also, notice this is **not** a Poisson distribution, for which you would have $P(X=k)=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$, for $k\geq 0$. Probabilities have not the same form, and moreover, for your distribution, $E(X)\neq V(X)$. Indeed, $E(X)=2\ln 2$ and $V(X)=2\ln2(1-\ln2)$.

Comment: Can you please explain a little, the former part of your solution ?

Comment: @MojoJojo Better now?

Comment: Yeah , Thanks !

Comment: Updated: notice the sum is from $k=1$, hence its value is $\exp x$, minus the summand for $k=0$, which is $1$.

Comment: Can you please provide some link that has the summation part explained? Understood the concept but still stuck on summation. Will be very helpful to me. Thanks.

Comment: @MojoJojo Well, it's the usual Taylor series expansion of the exponential. Have a look on Wikipedia: [Exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function), [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series). When you see $x^k/k!$ in a sum, it should immediately come to mind.

Comment: Thank you.  I had confused it with expectency.